# Showing that gravitational flux remains constant.

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces, vector-analysis

Let the vector field

$$\vec{F}(x,y,z)=\frac{GM}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^\frac32}
\begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y\\
z\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Where $G$ is the universal gravitational constant and $M$ the mass of earth. I must demonstrate that the **flux** of this vector field is constant throughout all 7 atmosphere layers at a distance $R_1, R_1,...,R_7$ from Earth.

I tried hard, but could someone please help me get started with this? The whole demonstration is supposed to take a single line.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem

Comment: Be careful, the divergence of this vector field is a Delta-Dirac distribution.

Comment: Actually, they are NOT constant.

Comment: A curious thing about the way this problem is worded: the flux of that vector field is constant not only across all atmosphere layers but also is the same flux through a sphere of radius $1$ km at the center of the earth is the same as the flux through the surface of the Earth, although in reality one flux is billions of times larger than the other. So sure, we can prove the statement, but how does it have practical significance, or any meaning other than as a mathematical curiosity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:**

For $\vec r\ne 0$, $\nabla \cdot \vec F=0$.  Now use the Divergence Theorem for any spherical shell (i.e., $0<r_1<r<r_2$ for any $0<r_1<r_2$) and show that the net flux is zero.

**SPOILER ALERT:**  CLICK ON THE SHADED AREA TO SEE ANSWER

> For $r>0$, we have $\nabla \cdot \vec F=0$.  Then, using the [Divergence Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem#Mathematical_statement) we observe that for $0<r_1<r_2$,$$\begin{align}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\int_{r_1}^{r_2}\nabla \cdot \vec F(\vec r)\,r^2\,dr\,\sin \theta\,d\theta\,d\phi&=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\vec F(r_2,\theta,\phi)\cdot \hat r\,r_2^2\,\sin \theta\,d\theta\,d\phi\\\\&-\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\vec F(r_1,\theta,\phi)\cdot \hat r\,r_1^2\,\sin \theta\,d\theta\,d\phi\\\\&=0\end{align}$$This implies that$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\vec F(r_2,\theta,\phi)\cdot \hat r\,r_2^2\,\sin \theta\,d\theta\,d\phi=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\vec F(r_1,\theta,\phi)\cdot \hat r\,r_1^2\,\sin \theta\,d\theta\,d\phi\\\\$$ 
> and therefore the flux is invariant.

Comment: But if you use the divergence theorem you have to take $\vec{r}=\vec{0}$. And $\nabla\cdot\vec{F}\neq\vec{0}$ for $\vec{r}=\vec{0}$. The net flux is not zero!

Comment: If you use the divergence theorem then you have to integrate $\nabla\cdot\vec{F}$ over the volume whose boundary is one of these spherical shells. This volume includes the origin.

Comment: The divergence theorem states that you can instead of integrating the flux of a vector field through a surface you can integrate the divergence of a vector field over a volume whose boundary is the given surface. If you are finding the flux through a spherical shell by using the divergence theorem, then the volume whose boundary is the spherical shell is a solid sphere which includes the origin.

Comment: Doesn't it seem strange that a radial field would have no flux through a spherical surface? Do you not agree that the space inside this spherical shell (the volume) contains the origin? If you do agree then review the divergence theorem and see that the region of integration does include origin and that there is a nonzero flux through any spherical shell.

Comment: @Dr.MV - forget it, your answer is nice and mathematical correct. Physical not ;) +1

Comment: @Dr. MV "block with an elementary concept" please don't belittle others. What was not included before (that you showed that two fluxes were equal by taking their difference and applying divergence theorem to show that the difference was zero, led to my confusion. Good work, sorry for our miscommunication. +1

Comment: @johannesvalks I am shocked by the comment.  Why do you believe that it is not physical?  The divergence of a vector is defined as $\lim_{\Delta V}\frac{\oint_S \vec F\cdot \hat n dS}{\Delta V}$, which is the "flux per unit volume" at a point.  And this approach makes perfect sense to me, a former professor of electromagnetic field theory - a branch of mathematical physics that relies on vector calculus.

Comment: @Tucker Sincere apology for my statement.  It apparently was my fault for leaving too much to interpretation.  And I had my 4th surgery in the past 15 months 5 weeks ago and recovering at home.  So, perhaps a bit impatient.  I hope we can be MSE friends.

Comment: @Dr.MV - don't be shocked! Atmosphere contains mass - so the flux increases.

Comment: Ah.  I was operating under an ideal assumption.  Got it now.

Answer (score 1):

I will go into a little more detail then Batominovski but take a similar approach by not using the divergence theorem and having to deal with the divergence of this field. I will using spherical coordinates, in these coordinates

$$\vec{F}=\frac{GM}{r^{2}}\hat{r}$$

$$d\vec{A}=r^{2}\hat{r}sin(\phi)d\phi d\theta$$

$$d\Phi=\vec{F}\cdot d\vec{A}=GMsin(\phi)d\phi d\theta$$

$$\Phi=\int d\Phi=GM\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}sin(\phi)d\phi d\theta$$

$$\Phi=4\pi GM$$

This flux is independent of the nonzero radius that we take.

Comment: Well done!  +1 Very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

**A non-Calculus Approach:**

Consider a solid angle $\delta\Omega$ at the center of the Earth.  The area subtending this solid angle at radius $r$ from the center of the Earth is $r^2\,\delta\Omega$.  The gravitational force is radial and its strength at radius $r$ is given by $-\frac{GM}{r^2}$ (the minus sign means that the force is directed inwards to the center of the Earth).  This means the gravitational flux through this area is $$-\frac{GM}{r^2}\cdot r^2\,\delta\Omega=-GM\,\delta\Omega\,.$$  Hence, the flux through any area subtended by this solid angle does not depend on the radius $r$.  In fact, the total flux can be calculated by taking $\delta\Omega=4\pi$, which gives $-4\pi GM$.

Comment: Why not take infinitesimal solid angle and integrate?

Comment: You can see it that way, but integration is not necessary here.

Comment: I agree, with the vector field being radial.

Answer (score 0):

Some notes on the question.

It is better to write $\vec{g}$ and the sign should be negative as the field points TOWARDS the Earth. So better to write

> $$
> \vec{g} = - G M \frac{ x \hat{x} + y \hat{y} + z \hat{z} }{r^3}. \tag 1
> $$

---

By definition we have

> $$
> \textrm{Flux} = \int_S \vec{g} \cdot d\vec{A}.\tag {2a}
> $$

We have the divergence theorem

> $$
> \int_V \vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{g} dV = \int_S \vec{g} \cdot d\vec{A}.\tag {2b}
> $$

And we have Poisson's equation

> $$
> \vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{g} = - 4 \pi G \rho. \tag {2c}
> $$

Combine them and we get

> $$
> \textrm{Flux} = - 4\pi G \int_V \rho dV. \tag 3
> $$

Thus

> $$
> \textrm{Flux} = - 4\pi G m_V. \tag 4
> $$

where $m_V$ is the mass INSIDE the volume $V$.

Consider volumes as spheres with radius $R$ and let $R_0$ be the radius of the Earth and let $M_0$ be the mass of the Earth.
NOTE that all layers have mass as well!

The mass inside the sphere $R_n$ is then given by

> $$
> \sum_{k=0}^n M_k. \tag 5
> $$

So the flux between $R_n$ and $R_{n+1}$ is given by

> $$
> - 4 \pi G \sum_{k=0}^n M_k. \tag 6
> $$

So
$$
\bbox[16px,border:2px solid #800000] { \textrm{The flux is NOT constant.} }
$$

But as $M_k << M_0$ for $k > 0$, it is almost constant.

Comment: The problem asks for the flux of "this vector field."  It doesn't include gravitational effects of the atmosphere.  Hence, with what it says, the statement to be proven is still correct (i.e., the flux is constant, not just almost constant as you said).

Comment: @Batominovski - even an atmosphere of 1 kilogram would change the $g$ field. So "this vector field" does not represent Earth INCLUDING atmosphere.

Comment: @Tucker - it is true, I have done the calculation and it is in the post. The flux is proportional to the amount of mass INSIDE the sphere - as the spheres increase, so does the mass as the atmosphere contains mass as well.

Comment: But we are integrating over shells that are away from the surface of the earth. So each will contain the same mass.

Comment: @Tucker, Nope - when the shell passes $R_1$ - the mass of $M_1$ has to be included. That mass is small - but it is not zero.

Comment: @johannesvalks  The question is not whether the vector field given here represents the gravitational force around the Earth.  It asks: **IF** THIS IS THE VECTOR FIELD, show that the flux due to "THIS VECTOR FIELD" is radius-independent.  You are being too pedantic here.

Comment: @Batominovski, sure - that is why the OP starts with **Where G is the universal gravitational constant and M the mass of earth.**

Comment: @johannesvalks  These are just the setups of the problem with assumptions.  What is wrong with that?

Comment: @johannesvalks if we take a spherical shell whose center corresponds with that of the earth and whose radius is larger than that of the earth then the flux is constant. Your analysis is correct if we take spherical shells whose radius is smaller then the radius of the earth. I just assumed that we were focusing on spherical shells whose radii were larger than that of the Earth.

Comment: @Batominovski, they are not physical.

Comment: @Tucker, nope. atmosphere has mass, larger shells contain more mass then Earth alone. To give you an idea, the mass of the atmosphere is about $5.1480 \times 10^{18} \texttt{kg}$ - it is small compared to Earth - but it HAS mass. That mass is added to sphere with radii larger then Earth.

Comment: @johannesvalks  That is not the point of the problem, is it?  It doesn't care whether the assumptions correspond to the real world.  If you are going to be pedantic, I can be too.  First, the gravitational force around the Earth is not radial, due to the fact that the Earth is not perfectly spherical.  Please include that in your calculation.  Second, the atmosphere is not stationary.  It is time-dependent.  Please include it as well.

Comment: @Batominovski, glad we have settled the dispute.